# N * N matrix by Java

Tags: java

This is what I written:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JavaTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String numberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number here: ",
            null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        int number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
        printMatrix(number);
    }

public static void printMatrix(int n){
    int[][] myList = new int[n][n];
    String output = "";

    for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++){
        for (int col = 1; col <= n; col++){
            myList[row][col] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
        }
    }
    for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++){
        for (int col = 1; col <= n; col++){
            if (col == n){
                output += "\n" + myList[row][col];
            }
            else{
                output += myList[row][col] + " ";
            }
        }
    }


    if (n < 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Invalid input!");
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                output);
    }
    }
}
```

I run it and enter 3 in a dialog box, and the eclipse IDE shows that

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at JavaTest.printMatrix(JavaTest.java:17)
    at JavaTest.main(JavaTest.java:8)
```

I guess at line 17 and 8 the program goes wrong but I don't know how to improve it.
What can I do to improve my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're looping from 1 to n:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++){
    for (int col = 1; col <= n; col++){
```

Indexes begin at 0, not at 1.  The loops should be from 0 to n-1:

```
for (int row = 0; row < n; row++){
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++){
```

(This same error may likely be in other places than just the first line that threw the exception.)